# Removing malware injecting into Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, mac, malware

I had seen this popup across different sites, but I realized my computer was infected once I got hit with it on stackexchange!

I'm using Google Chrome on Mac computer, and I've checked my extensions. Nothing is suspicious about the extensions I have.

How do I find the process running this code injection and remove it from my computer? And what tools are best for the job?

[image: Malware example]

The linked question is how to remove viruses from my PC. The question states that I have a Mac.

Comment: PC and Mac are two different things. Updated the question.

Comment: They are not. PCs and Macs are *exactly* the same. Windows and OS X are different, but the advice is really still the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend Malwarebytes as the tool to use to get rid of the adware.

[**Mac Version**](https://www.malwarebytes.com/mac-download/)

Found a simple walkthrough to help you remove some extensions manually as well (Not sure if you tried these steps already.)

[**Manually remove Extenstions**](https://malwaretips.com/blogs/remove-mac-os-x-virus/)

Comment: Accepted this answer because it outlines a software tool that I can use to remove malware on my machine, as described by the question above.